# Outlook add-in authentication accessing user data EWS or Graph

Tags: c#, office-js, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, azure-ad-msal

I am currently developing an Outlook add-in that needs to save the emails and attachments of our clients to our database. I've used the Microsoft document "Get attachments of an Outlook item from the server" that uses Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync and Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl to get a valid token to pass to our API. The API then executes the below code to authenticate and then download emails and attachments:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService
{
Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(request.AttachmentToken),
Url = new Uri(request.EwsUrl)
};
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item

Microsoft announced that they were going to eventually disable basic authentication for Exchange Online, but I can't find any documentation regarding if the above is consider basic, thus requires updating. If anyone knows the answer to this please let me know.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-july-update/ba-p/1530163

I have also been working on utilising Microsoft Graph with the add-in as is recommended by Microsoft. Currently the user experience isn't completely user friendly whilst authenticating and refreshing tokens with MSAL.JS (Microsoft authentication library) on desktop Outlook. As my company's project has our frontend (React) on a different domain to our API (.NET 5.0) we can't implement the SSO method as Microsoft requires the add-in and its backend to be on the same domain. Below is a statement from Authorize to Microsoft Graph with SSO documentation:

"JavaScript in the add-in makes an HTTP request to a web API that is hosted at the same fully-qualified domain as the add-in, and it includes the bootstrap access token as authorization proof.

I've instead attempted to implement Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow based off the following repository:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-spa-dotnetcore-webapi-obo

This solution works, but desktop Outlook using MSAL.JS requires the authentication to occur in Office Dialog boxes causing a less than optimal UE. The short life of the tokens and the silentRequestToken also needing to be run in a Dialog box are my current issue. If anyone knows a better method of implementation please let me know.

Both methods get the same information, with the first method not requiring user interaction, but potentially being made disabled and the second method requiring too much user interaction. If anyone could please recommend the best course of actions?

Comment: With your EWS code that isn't basic Authentication and won't be affected by disabling of Basic auth. These are Service Callback Tokens https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/mail-apps-for-outlook-and-ews-in-exchange vs basic Authentication which is basically you username and password in a header

Comment: Thank you very for this comment @GlenScales this solves my problem.